# Does the energy of electron moving through a vacuum chamber remain constant?

Tags: kinematics, electrons, energy-conservation, quantum-electrodynamics, classical-electrodynamics

If an electron moves through a vacuum chamber of infinite size, What will happen of its energy? Does it (energy of the electron) remain constant until it interacts with the other object? 
............................
If it's not enough to understand, please see my comment.
"Suppose, an electron is ejected from a metal surface...".

Comment: -1 Not clear what you are asking. Why do you think its energy might change?

Comment: Is there an electric field in this vacuum chamber?

Comment: Suppose, an electron is ejected from a metal surface by the interaction of a photon with the matter. Now if the matter belongs to a vacuum of an infinite area, the electron moves through the vacuum being ejected from the metal surface. What will happen to its energy? Does it (energy of the electron) remain constant until it interacts with other object or any force field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the energy will stay constant until it interacts with some othe particle or force field.